# How to implement Site Search Google Analytics in Angular 4 applications

Tags: angular, google-analytics

My angular 4 application have Search functionality, I need to track what user is searching in that search bar by using Google Analytics, how to implement this?
FYI: The application URL doesn't have query string or filter..

Comment: Hi Folks, any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for `gtag` script:

1. `gtag` analytics script should be already added to application
2. Create some service for analytics logic:

```
declare var gtag: any;

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AnalyticsService {
  trackSearch(query: string): void {
    gtag('event', 'search', {
      search_term: query
    });
  }
}
```

3. Use it in the handler where you initialize the search, for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<button (click)="search('search term')"></button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private readonly analyticsService: AnalyticsService) {
  }

  search(query: string): void {
    // your search functional
    this.analyticsService.trackSearch(query);
  }
}
```

Comment: @tarun92 was it helpful for you?